# How do you disable CheckBoxes in ListView?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

[image]

If you type a word on the "txtProdBarcode" section, the lists will come at the bottom like the picture. The list sections name is "lvBase" which is a`ListView`.

Then when you type a word on the "searchText" section, the checkboxes on the "lvBase" section shouldn't be clickable. I don't want to remove the checkboxes, but want to prevent them from being checked.

I've tried my best but can't get the answer.

```
private void txtProdBarcode_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string searchText = txtProdBarcode.Text.ToUpper().Trim();

    if (searchText.Length > 0)
    {                  
        lvBase.CheckBoxes = false;                          
    }
    else
    {
        lvBase.CheckBoxes = true;
    }
```

This code deletes the checkboxes on the "lvBase" section.

But I want only the checkboxes to be disabled.

Can you guys help me to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the 'lvBase' control type? Can't you disable that control so that none inside it can be accessed or clicked?

Comment: have you tried `.IsEnabled = false` ?

Comment: It seems that your lvBase is some custom control based on the System.Windows.Forms.ListView, it manipulates checkboxes in its own custom way and we can't know how it does that. However, its .CheckBoxes property should contain some functionality related to checkboxes. If you could look it up and update your question with code from that property, we could help you to find a solution for your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent checking items of `ListView`, you can handle [`ItemCheck`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.itemcheck?view=netframework-4.7.2) event:

```
bool preventCheck = true;
private void listView1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    if (preventCheck)  // for example: !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)
        e.NewValue = e.CurrentValue;
}
```